# Print a screenshot from web page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html2canvas

I'm creating a web page and I need to make a button that prints a selected area. After several searches everything led me to implement [html2canvas](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/).
I installed it with 
***npm install html2canvas*** in the command prompt. In the official html2canvas website they mention 
***import html2canvas from 'html2canvas';*** that I suppose I need to add in the top of my aspx file(?)
So far I've coded this code portion:

```js
function getScreenshot() {
  alert("bob");
  html2canvas(document.body, {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
      var canvasImg = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpg");
      $('#test').html('<img src="' + canvasImg + '" alt="">');
    }
  });
  var printContent = document.getElementById("row");
  var printWindow = window.open("", "");
  printWindow.document.write(printContent.innerHTML);
  printWindow.document.write("<script src=\'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js\'><\/script>");
  printWindow.document.write("<script>$(window).load(function(){ print(); close(); });<\/script>");
  printWindow.document.close();
};
```

```html
<div id="test" class="body-content animated fadeIn">
  <a href="javascript:getScreenshot()">
    <img src="Images/printer.png" width="40" height="40" align="right">
  </a>
</div>
```

The issue is when I click the button, no window opens for printing. The button works for sure because I get the alert window.
What am I missing for this to work? Can be a installation procedure? Can be bad attributes implementation?

Comment: I guess the problem is simply that the html2canvas lib is not loaded. npm install will install it in node_modules and that's in most cases outside your document root (wwwroot). You should check your browsers debug console for errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make sure that you're including your script file correctly. There should be a `<script>` tag that includes a web-compatible version of your library. Most instructions that use `npm install ...`; `import ...` assume that you are using a web bundler like webpack or rollup to make a single bundled JavaScript file, or are using the new es6 module importer. That doesn't look like what you're doing here.

Instead, you can include a prebuilt version of html2canvas, like from https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/dist/html2canvas.js or https://unpkg.com/html2canvas@1.0.0-alpha.12/dist/html2canvas.js.

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/html2canvas@1.0.0-alpha.12/dist/html2canvas.js"></script>
```

You can see a working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/u8Lz32k0/7/

Comment: It seems very clean and clear your working example, I will use it! Just give me one more light please, why nothing is print besides a date?

Comment: It should be printing the document, which you can add more things to. For me, it prints the text too. If it's not working, wrapping `printWindow.print()` in a `setTimeout` might do the trick, like in this updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/u8Lz32k0/7/

Comment: Yeaaaah much better!

Comment: Only issue I'm getting is enter all the web page in the printed page and some colors changes

Comment: I haven't used html2canvas before, but it sounds like it could be an issue with it.

Comment: @Steve fiddle does not exist. can you please update it. thanks

Comment: @AhmadKarim, it seems to still work for me-- let me know if you still can't see it

Answer (score 1):

Working fiddle: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b9w5e1zt/).

I would recommend opening a new html page where you include the element you're trying to print, along with a button "Print This Page" as is showed in the example below. And once user clicks on that button, thats when the browser's print page opens up.

This is the working function, all you need to do is **call this function on click** from your website's page, and **change YOUR_ELEMENT** to your container's id (#row in you case).

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  function OpenPrintPage() {

   var OriginalContent = document.getElementById('YOUR_ELEMENT').innerHTML;
   var PrintWindow =  window.open("","PrinterFriendlyPage","scrollbars=yes,status=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=yes,resizable=yes,height=510,width=750"); 
   
   PrintWindow.document.write( '<html><head><title>' + document.title +'</title></head><body><div id="' + 'content' + '">' + '</div><a class="printbtn" href="javascript:window.print()">Print This Page</a> </body></html>'); 

   PrintWindow.document.close(); 
   PrintWindow.document.getElementById('content').innerHTML += OriginalContent; 
  }

 </script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot but I don't understand... I did what you've told me and nothing happens besides the alert window I added to make sure the button works. The main reason I use html2canvas is because when I do cntl+p it distorts the structure of the page. What do you suggest me to do?

Comment: @RaphClc did you try editing the fiddle i enclosed to suit your needs (like adding images)? the solution I offered is mostly for capturing information like text and maybe some images here and there since you can include <style> tag inside of PrintWindow.document.write() but it would definitely get messy if you're trying to capture the page that uses a lot of css. on the other side, i don't really have experience working with html2canvas, so unfortunately i can't help you with it

Answer (score -1):

Have you loaded the script in your web page? Can you post the beginning of your HTML file where you show all your imports?

Comment: if you are asking question, put it in comments.

Comment: I can't comment without enough reputation, however this question is necessary to resolve the asker's problem